# Oracle ORA-06502 numeric or value error on a procedure in c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I created the following procedure:

```
create or replace procedure ps_medical (
   v_id in number,
   v_name out varchar2,
   v_description out varchar2
) is
begin
select name, description 
  into v_name, v_description 
  from medical_img 
  where id = v_id;
end;
```

It rises Oracle ORA-06502 numeric or value error. I want to display v_name and v_description.

My table structure:

```
ID            NOT NULL NUMBER                   
NAME          VARCHAR2(255)            
DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR2(255)
```

In Sql Developer it works fine. I'm trying to use it in a c# form and there the error rises:

```
try
{
    con.Open();
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("ps_medical", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("v_id", OracleDbType.Int32);
cmd.Parameters.Add("v_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
cmd.Parameters.Add("v_description", OracleDbType.Varchar2);

cmd.Parameters[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

cmd.Parameters[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(tb_id.Text);

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    lb_med.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters[1].Value);
    tb_desc.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters[2].Value);
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: If you're getting an error ... then you definitely want to FIX the error!  Q: Where exactly is the error occurring?  When you compile your stored procedure?  When some application invokes it?  Please update your post, showing exactly where the error occurs (including code), and copy/paste the (full!) error text?

Comment: In sql developer it works fine. I'm trying to use it in a c# form and there it rises (I displayed the error text in a MessageBox).

Comment: Then there is a sizing/type issue in your C# code.  Please edit the question and show that.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small exception from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899765/ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-character-string-buffer-too-small-exc)

Answer (score 1):

I added the size and now it works.

cmd.Parameters.Add("v_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255);

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm#ODPNT2286), Oracle `NUMBER`corresponds to .Net `OracleDbType.Decimal`.  Please see if changing to "Decimal" resolves the problem.